# Consider the function $f_X(x) = (a e^{-x} + b e^{-2x}) u(x)$. Find constants a and b that would make this a valid pdf.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I am new to this. So far I have always encountered questions which give clear interval of x for the pdf function. I also don't understand the presence of u(x) in the question. The question is:

Consider the function $f_X(x) = (a e^{-x} + b e^{-2x}) u(x)$. Find constants a and b that would make this a valid pdf.

Could you please help me with this?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. A question should be written in such a way that it can be understood even by someone who did not read its title.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, I edited the question.

Comment: I believe this question is not well formulated. As $u(x)$ is not specified I can't see a way to define $a$ and $b$ in such a way to ensure that $f(x)$ is a valid PDF.

Comment: I know right! Something doesn't seem right with this. But a bunch of such questions were asked on a previous quiz in class. So I assumed maybe I am missing something.